# react native typescript why I get 2x is_verified object ? How can I get only 1x

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I have a interface named user

```
export interface CurrentUser {
  user_id: number;
  is_verified?: boolean;
}
```

So then I want to add a verified component.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { CurrentUser } from '../../store/slice/Auth/Auth';

const Verified = (is_verified: Pick<CurrentUser, 'is_verified'>) => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Verified</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default Verified;
```

The problem is now I can access 2x is_verified like this:

```
is_verified.is_verified
```

How can I make it only one time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
const Verified = ({ is_verified }: CurrentUser>) => {
```

Explanation:

Functional components are called with the props object as the first argument. My version destructures the named prop out of the `props` object. Since your version doesn't do this, the whole object is called `is_verified`, which is why you have to access the prop you want from that object.